# How do I fix the "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type" error?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Print("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Whenever I try using things like print's or if statements or anything like that (Like using `UserDefaults` for saving settings for another example) outside of an action then it gives me the "Function declares an opaque return type", but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type".

With `UIKit` whatever thing like that you put in the `viewDidLoad()` would run perfectly so is there something like `viewDidLoad()` for `SwiftUI` ? If not how would I go about performing these actions (and before you say taking them out of the body and putting them in the `ContentView` that'll just give me the "Expected declaration" error)?

Comment: You need to return a View.

Comment: @matt what do you mean? Can you give me a example?

Comment: For example: `print("hello world"); return Text("hello world")`

Comment: You cannot say just anything you want in SwiftUI `body`. This is a domain-specific language. It's not the old Swift.

Comment: This is not Cocoa. It’s a completely different paradigm. Watch the videos and do the tutorials.

Comment: @matt figured it out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830108/10919715 this'll make writing code much easier since you'll never have to worry about this error ever again.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the body of the view, ***must*** return a View:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Additionally, a large amount of restrictions are in place when defining the body.

There's no way around it. You need to read the documentation, or at least follow these tutorials from Apple, which are very well put together:

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56830108/10919715 figured out a way around it, it's actually a lot simpler than it seems.

Comment: There are no equivalents with UIKit and view cycles are completely different. You ***need*** to read the documentation, or you be bumping into all kinds of unexpected compiler error. With SwiftUI error messages are completely misleading and many times they will be reported in the wrong place. For example, it may tell you there is an error at the beginning of your code, when the problem is really 300 lines of code below.

Comment: @kontiki which docs? I find the Apple developer documentation to be very sparse.

Answer (score -6):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        var bodyView: some View {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        //Put your entire UI in the bodyView, between the bodyView and "return bodyView" you can put what you would as if it was a viewDidLoad() like in UIKit.
        return bodyView
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you need `bodyView` in the first place and not use the `body` directly.

Comment: Injecting non-view related code into the `body` property is just not how SwiftUI works